# Minesweeper Kata, how to manage and change tests to reflect design in TDD?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

I'm doing Minesweeper Kata http://codingdojo.org/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?KataMinesweeper

I decided to start with grid creation and have some questions about organization of growing tests base.

First thing I did was to create tests (and implement what they require) like that in MineSweeperTest class:

```
@Test
public void testCreateGridWithRightDimensions() {
    String[][] grid = new MineSweeper().toGrid(field);
    // ...
}
```

next

```
@Test
public void testFillGridWithFieldData() {
    String[][] grid = new MineSweeper().toGrid(field);
    // ...
}
```

then

```
@Test
public void fillMultipleGrids() {
    String[][] grid = new MineSweeper().toGrid(fields);
    // ...
}
```

Now as I have working fields to grids translation working I'm gonna to clean up my solution a bit and have few questions:

For now I'm using String[][] as grid and I'd like to introduce new concept of Grid object. Does it mean I should move those tests from MineSweeperTest to GridTest and change tests to use Grid like that:

```
new Grid(field);
```

and in the future implement something like:

```
grid.isSafeField(row, col);
```

What about grid's internals? I don't want my sweeper class to know about the fact that my Grid is based on array of arrays of strings. 
If so, my current tests get useless and need to be changed, but I can't see a way to do that.

If you could point me into the right direction I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that using a `Grid` instead of a `String[][]` is probably the right way to go.  To perform assertions on the `Grid`, you can compare it to `Grids` you create in the test using a factory constructor or Hamcrest matchers.

Here is how a test might look:

```
@Test
public void sweepingAMineShouldMakeItDissapear() {
   Grid unswept = Grid.grid(".*",
                            "..");
   unswept.sweep(2, 1);
   assertEquals(unswept, grid("..",
                              "..");
}
```

Or you might have different symbols for hidden mines vs revealed mines.

Comment: It's nice way. I haven't thought about that, thanks. But what about existing tests? Now the first one about grid dimensions gets impossible to check unless I create method for size checking on Grid (but I don't want to, as it isn't required in my API)

Comment: You should be creating your tests **because** they are required by your API.  If a test is not required to make the program work, then why write it?  On the other hand, if a class is too complicated to test by itself, then you refactor out a delegate that you can test.